# Android Studio builds two applications for the same project simultaenously

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-library

I'm making an app using Android Studio v0.5.9, which has a **library project** as a dependency. But, every time I run the project two apks having the same name and icon, are deployed to my device. The first apk(app) contains my main module, whereas, the second one is the library project itself. However, when I run the same project from Eclipse, only one apk is deployed and it works perfectly.

Here are some screenshots of the problem -

[image]

First App(My module) -

[image]

Second App(library project) -

[image]

top-level `build.gradle` file -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

main module `build.gradle` file -

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        packageName 'com.Swap.Rooms'
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':lib')
}
```

library project `build.gradle` file -

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        packageName "com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager"
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

`settings.gradle` -

```
include ':app'
include ':lib'
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Share you gradle file please

Comment: @EugenMartynov I've added the `build.gradle` files, please take a look.

Comment: How do you connect two project. Can you share `settings.gradle`?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I've added the `settings.gradle` file. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't see anything that could produce two apks. Is this library that you use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager?

Comment: @EugenMartynov yes...

Comment: Just in case, if you remove two apps, is Android Studio installs both of them again?

Comment: @EugenMartynov yeah Android Studio reinstalls two apks... Even if export the project as a signed apk and install it locally, two apks automatically get installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55446/discussion-between-eugen-martynov-and-swap).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful for others.

Gradle is doing manifest merge for library projects as well. So issue was to keep `AndroidManifes.xml` unchanged from library. It had `application` node for demo purposes and this node was successfully merged to main `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I'm going to submit issue to Google since I think it should prevent or warn about such situation.

Comment: You can use the Android manifest merge tools option "remove" to override merge behavior on each node in the library project's manifest: In the case of JazzyViewPager, add tools:node="remove" to the <activity> node for the MainActivity.  (NOTE: this is for version 0.8.2 of Android Studio, as they recently changed the manifest merge tools)

Answer (score 6):

Eugen Martynov answer is correct but i decided to reiterate what he said in layman's terms.

Go through your libraries and check their `AndroidManifest.xml`. One of them should have an `<application>` tag in it. Remove the tag and the double app problem will be solved.

Comment: Kita's answer is [more] correct. Your library might have not only an application tag, it might also have an Activity defined in it! As long as it does not have the Launcher filter intents, your good to go.

Answer (score 5):

The specific element in the ApplicationManifest.xml, that affects creating multiple launcher icons is the `<intent-filter>` containing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`. Removing this `<intent-filter>` will give you control over the number of launcher icons. You can read a bit more elaborate SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292442/760211).

Answer (score 2):

It took me time to realize where the issue was.But finaly worked out for me.
The issue is with the `Manifest.xml` file. It means that you  have two activities set as `LAUNCHER`.
just remove the code simmilar to the one below from the activity that is not your `LAUNCHER`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```