# Running app gives 2 app icons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running an app in Android Studio and it gives 2 app icons in Androi Studio.

Also, I have moved from Eclipse to Android Studio and now I'm having trouble with how to make the color of logcat same as in Eclipse.

My question is that there are 2 app icons when I run the app, and when I uninstall it, 2 of them have been removed. Is that normal in Android Studio?
I have found that Android Studio can copy keys from Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mytrack.ph"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!--  Google Map v.2 permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!--  GCM permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <!--  Writing Persmission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACT"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name="com.mytrack.ph.SplashActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:noHistory="true" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mytrack.ph.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           >
        </activity>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_map_api_key"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <service android:name="com.my.track.service.MyTrackService"></service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.my.track.service.MyTrackGcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.my.track.service" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.my.track.service.MyTrackGcmIntentService" />
        <activity android:name="NavigationMenuActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             ></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.track.results.ConnectionChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I though this is normal in android studio. Running an app gives 2 launcher icons.
PS:

my `AndroidManifest.xml` is inside *main* folder and I used eclipse to export to gradle build.

Im using Android Studio 0.8.6
thanks.

Comment: Post your manifest file. Make sure you are not defining two activities which both have intent filters which specify the LAUNCHER category.

Comment: no i didnt define 2 launcher type activities.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: the top build ? or project build?

Comment: im really confused with these builds they are everywhere

Comment: top and project files

Comment: solved it ! thanks guys, I never knew there was another AndroidManifest.xml , i thought eclipse removed it. and i thought Exporting it to gradle will remove it because it is checked as a library.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I got it! yes at last , i have to study gradles and stuff.

Actually I have 2 android projects inside the Project, one is a library and the other one is the main app.

I found out that when i imported those projects Android Studio (I exported the lib to gradle build from eclipse) doesn't care if that is a lib project or a main project. (Correct me if im wrong ).

so the only thing to make it work is to remove the `intent-filter` of that lib-android-project.

EDIT: 
@all
solved it ! thanks to everyone, I never knew there was another AndroidManifest.xml , i thought eclipse removed it. and i thought Exporting it to gradle will remove it because it is checked as a library.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: also if you have attribute like this `<application android:label=" android:icon=">` remove them `<application>`

Comment: I just had this problem on an app with two activities, removed the intent-filter on my second activity and it removed the two app problem!

Answer (score 45):

The `<intent-filter>` that affects creating multiple launcher icon is the following one:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

Android Studio's [manifest merger](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) will always combine `<intent-filter>`s in library projects into main project's manifest. You may end up having multiple `LAUNCHER` intents in your synthesized manifest, thus having multiple launcher icons. To avoid this, simply remove the `LAUNCHER` intents from the library projects' manifest.

Answer (score 13):

You declare two intent filter, used only one Intent filter in the activity, on AndroidManifest.

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

If you used two or more intent filter in AndroidManifest, then you will have two app icon, So remove it & set one intent filter.

I hove this is usedful to you.

Answer (score 8):

i agree, since i made 2 activity(one for splash, one for main). In manifest i forgot to delete

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

so in the end when i install app, i will have 2 app.

Comment: this should be a comment please

Answer (score 7):

There is most likely an imported Library project that has this intent filter.

```
1. Open your app manifest
2. At the bottom left click on "Merged Manifest"
3. Search and find which library project has the attribute

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
4. Remove it and ensure that now the filter is only on your App's <Application >class activity.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was just because, in the manifest file, two activities were declared as launcher. Actually, I clicked on the launcher checkbox while making new activity, thinking it will transfer the launcher tag from the previous activity to this, but it created both activities as launchers.

Answer (score -1):

When running android and doing debug, there is an another AndroidManifest.xml under src/debug. Make sure this manifest file matches the main one under src/main.

Answer (score -3):

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

       <!You need to delete launcher intent filter from every other activity ->

    </activity>
```

The "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" intent filter decides which activity will launch when you tap on the application icon. If there are more than 1 entries, OS will create more than one app icon after installation. You need to make sure that there is a single entry of above intent filter in the Manifest file.