# Two apps after react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-redux, react-native

I'm making a react native app and earlier it was working fine but now when I run "react-native run-android", after the successful install and launch, I can see two apps in the simulator and both of them are working fine.
So, any ideas why I'm seeing 2 apps or should I say why I'm getting an extra duplicate app installed?

Answer (score 29):

I think you added splash screen in your app after it you have this problem, first go to this Dir: `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` if you add two time something like this

```
       <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity> -->
```

it will render two times and build two apps on your device.

in my file

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- remove just first part the activity, but i comment this part -->

  <!-- <activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity> -->



  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: yes, this is the problem but how to solve this. If I remove this then will splash screen work

Comment: usually after the add splash screen, in your androidManifest file will add the second activity, just remove the first activity and it will be solved.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is due to multiple category LAUNCHER in both splash and main activity.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

The solution with both SplashActivity and MainActivity is to change

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

to

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

in MainActivity.

The file with both .SplashActivity and .MainActivity looks like this;

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue as well. It turns out one of RN lib I installed created an extra `<activity />` and `<intent-filter />`tags. Just check your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My source: [Running app gives 2 app icons in Android Studio - newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763896/running-app-gives-2-app-icons-in-android-studio-newbie)

Answer (score 8):

Change this

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true"
      >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

To

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true"
      />
```

Basically you have two intent-filters delete one

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer Aras posted above, for me the issue was specifically with the extra `intent-filter` attributes which were labeled 'MAIN' and 'LAUNCHER'. You can't have more than one occurrence of those without creating duplicate apps, it seems.

```
       <activity
         android:name=".SplashActivity"
         android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
         <!-- You'll either want to remove this section, or ensure that it does not exist in any other activities. -->
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to simply do is checkout for

```html
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

within the App AndroidManifest.xml file, there's more likely you have multiple launchers defined in your app's manifest file. You can try removing any extra launchers.

Try clearing the cache and rebuild your app.

Answer (score -2):

Check the package name of the installed apps.

Comment: How? I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: In android menu, go to APPs and check the two apps, they MUST have differents package names