# Multiple APKS installed of the same app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm not entirely sure how or why this is happening, but when I install my app, There are 2 apks that are installed. They have the same name and they have the same icon. One (top right, circled in red) force closes and the other (bottom left, circled in yellow) works just fine. But I dont want 2, only 1. Below is my manifest as Im sure that is where the issue is happening.

EDIT: I believe it has something to do with the servicestarter activity but I'm not sure what.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="bladebeat.pro.swipeup" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application tools:replace="android:icon , android:theme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceStarter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name=".Servers.SearchManager"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is the package the same for the other app ?

Comment: i assume so. Its all under the same project and manifest. When i uninstall both then re-run the app, Android Studio re-installs both again.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="bladebeat.pro.swipeup"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: No go. This didn't fix it. But i needed it anyway, so thanks for that lol

Comment: did you change your versionCode ?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Studio builds two applications for the same project simultaenously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106654/android-studio-builds-two-applications-for-the-same-project-simultaenously)

This was the problem. It actually had nothing to do with my Manifest and everything to do with my dependencies manifest. Problem solved though it should not have happened in the first place.